# How do I insert a select multiple options field to forms.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here is the html form code for the select option I would like to use for "lamps" & "painting" which has already been inserted:

```
<form action="#" id="ContactForm">
    <div class="success">Contact form submitted!
        <br>    <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong> 
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Name:</span>

            <label class="name">    <span class="bg"><input type="text" class="input"></span>
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>  <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Email:</span>

            <label class="email">   <span class="bg"><input type="text" class="input"></span>
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>  <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Phone:</span>

            <label class="phone">   <span class="bg"><input type="text" class="input"></span>
    <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span>  <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>

            </label>
        </div> <strong>Interested in:</strong>  <small style="font-size:10px">* Hold down the Ctrl/Command key to select multiple options.</small>

        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Lamps:</span>

            <label class="lamps notRequired">   <span class="bg"><select name="lamps" multiple>
                                                        <option value="Green Leaf">Green Leaf</option>
                                                        <option value="Colour Vault">Colour Vault</option>
                                                        <option value="Palace Tower">Palace Tower</option>
                                                        <option value="Sun Structure">Sun Structure</option>
                                                        <option value="Puzzled">Puzzled</option>
                                                        <option value="Colour Vault #2">Colour Vault #2</option>
                                                        <option value="Royal Velvet">Royal Velvet</option>
                                                        <option value="Royal Velvet #2">Royal Velvet #2</option>
                                                        <option value="Palace Tower #2">Palace Tower #2</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </span>
 <span class="error">*This is not a valid lamp selection.</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Paintings:</span>

            <label class="paintings notRequired">   <span class="bg"><select name="paintings" multiple>
                                                        <option value="The Maya">The Maya</option>
                                                        <option value="The Maya #2">The Maya #2</option>
                                                        <option value="The Maya #3">The Maya #3</option>
                                                        <option value="Mellow">Mellow</option>
                                                        <option value="Arizona at Dusk">Arizona at Dusk</option>
                                                        <option value="Festival">Festival</option>
                                                        <option value="The Flow">The Flow</option>
                                                        <option value="Summer Frost">Summer Frost</option>
                                                        <option value="Midnight in Mexico">Midnight in Mexico</option>
                                                        <option value="The Tunnel">The Tunnel</option>
                                                        <option value="Fusion">Fusion</option>
                                                        <option value="Gold Maya">Gold Maya</option>
                                                        <option value="Mexican Party Night">Mexican Party Night</option>
                                                        <option value="Aurora">Aurora</option>
                                                        <option value="Ghosts">Ghosts</option>
                                                        <option value="Crimson">Crimson</option>
                                                        <option value="Crimson #2">Crimson #2</option>
                                                        <option value="Colours on Holiday">Colours on Holiday</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </span>
 <span class="error">*This is not a valid painting selection.</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">   <span class="col1">Message:</span>

            <label class="message"> <span class="bg"><textarea rows="1" cols="1"></textarea></span>
    <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span>  <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btns"><a href="#" class="link1" data-type="submit" title="Send Inquiry">Send</a><a href="#" class="link1" data-type="reset" title="Clear Form Content">Clear</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the code mailHandler.php for which $_POST 'lamps' & 'paintings' has already been inserted:

```
<?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
$subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['lamps']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Lamps Interested In: ' . $_POST['lamps'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['paintings']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Paintings Interested In: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

`enter code here`?>

and here is the form.js file that I am trying to get working with the above html & php mailHandler:

```
;(function($){
$.fn.forms=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this)
            ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'xxxxx@xxxxx.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true,
                rx:{
                    ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                    ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                    ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                    ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                },
                preFu:function(){
                    _.labels.each(function(){
                        var label=$(this),
                            inp=$(_.targets,this),
                            defVal=inp.val(),
                            trueVal=(function(){
                                        var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                        return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                    })()
                        trueVal!=defVal
                            &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                        label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                        inp
                            .bind('focus',function(){
                                inp.val()==defVal
                                    &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            })
                            .bind('blur',function(){
                                _.validateFu(label)
                                if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                    inp.val(defVal)
                                    ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                            })
                            .bind('keyup',function(){
                                label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                    &&_.validateFu(label)
                            })
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                    })
                    _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired:function(el){                            
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid:function(el){                           
                    var ret=true
                    $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                        if(el.is(k))
                            ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                    })
                    return ret                          
                },
                isEmpty:function(el){
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu:function(el){                            
                    el.each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                            ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                            ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                            ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                        if(empty&&req)
                            _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                        else
                            _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                        if(!empty)
                            if(valid)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel:function(label){
                    var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                        ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                    return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                }
                ,submitFu:function(){
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                    if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                            data:{
                                name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function(){
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })          
                },
                showFu:function(){
                    _.success.slideDown(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        },_.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu:function(){
                    $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                        var th=$(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click',function(){
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                    label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init:function(){
                    _.form=_.me                     
                    _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit',function(){
                            if(_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset',function(){
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                            _.labels.each(function(){
                                var th=$(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
        typeof o=='object'
            &&$.extend(_,o)
    })
}
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('#ContactForm').forms({
        ownerEmail:'xxxxx@xxxxx.com'
    })
})
```

I have tried a few different ways but cannot get form to work properly or to actually send the select multiple option data via the email submissions of the form. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [] after the name of your select and this will tell PHP to expect an array e.g.

```
<select name="paintings[]" multiple>
```